# jQuery compare string to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a string comparison like so in JQuery

```
$('#select_directory_type').on('change', function() {
     window.alert($(this).val()); // I can see the selection is "SOMETHING"
     if( "SOMETHING" === $(this).val() ){
         // Never gets executed even when the selection is "SOMETHING".
     } });
```

Another question is, what is the difference between

```
$this.val()
and 
$(this).val()
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a searchable index of questions and answers. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: `$this` is not defined. If you are talking about the DOM syntax, you want `this.value` otherwise you need to explicitly defined `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Please, put an example for your broken code.

Comment: Post the HTML of the `#select_directory_type` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reverse order $(this).val() says, give jquery (represented by a $) the value this, and then call the function .val() on the return of that function. $this.val() is saying, call the function .val() on the variable $this, which i suspect you haven't defined.

It looks like your snippet of code *should* work, but === checks for exact string equality, I'd highly suggest you inspect your string in console using console.log, to verify it doesn't have any trailing whitespaces or similar. Replace your alert with console.log(), and look in the developer console (ctrl-shift-I on chrome). you could also

```
 console.log( "SOMETHING" === $(this).val())
```

to see if your issue is actually the comparison. Its most likely whitespace related though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The issue was the white space for string comparison failing.

Answer (score 0):

There might be extra whitespace on either end of the string. Try:

`if( "SOMETHING" === $(this).val().trim() )`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery syntax is generally `$(selector)`. If your case `this` is your selector so `$(this)` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: `this` isn't a selector, it's a DOM element, so this is an example of `$(element)`, not `$(selector)`.

Comment: Right. I used the d3.js nomenclature, selectors are based off of DOM elements.